# jquery cycle caption to show selected div

Tags: jquery

I'm working on this site:

www.dimitrinube.com/work/a2bc_beta1

as you can see, once loaded, there is a jquery cycle previewing projects. If you click the project section in the menu, it goes in the project list, and when you click a project, it opens up.

in the old version every project was stored in different html pages. Now, i did a single page layout with hidden divs.

The things that i cant make work anymore is the caption below the projects previews, under the cycle plugin.

In the old version there was:

```
$('#s2').cycle({
fx: 'scrollHorz',
speed: 500,
timeout: 0,
next: '#next2',
prev: '#prev2',
after: function(){$('#caption').html("<a href=" + this.alt + ">" + this.title + "</a>");}
});
```

but now, i have to link it to the hidden divs of each project: for instance; here is one hidden div:

```
<div class="content_pr" id="tab3">
<img src="img/projects/carcano/1.jpg" >
<img src="img/projects/carcano/2.jpg" >
<img src="img/projects/carcano/3.jpg" >
<img src="img/projects/carcano/4.jpg" >
<img src="img/projects/carcano/5.jpg" >
<img src="img/projects/carcano/6.jpg" >
<img src="img/projects/carcano/7.jpg" >
<img style="margin-bottom:0px" src="img/projects/carcano/8.jpg" >
</div>
```

that is identified by the id; the projects section work with this piece of code:

```
 //Handler Menu Progetti
function openTab(tab){    
$(tab).fadeTo(2000, 1);
}

$("#projects_tab a, #caption").click(function(){    
selectedTab = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#'));
openTab(selectedTab);
$("#projects_tab").hide();
$("#projects_b").removeClass('active');
});
```

how can i modify the string after of the jquery cycle piece of code to make the magic happens ? thank you ! :)

Comment: Cant quite understand what the problem is :(

Comment: i have to make the caption under the project preview slideshow actually linking to the project div..... as in project section does. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem but it's not perfect:

```
function openTab(tab){    
$(tab).fadeTo(2000, 1);
}

$('#s2').cycle({
fx: 'scrollHorz',
speed: 500,
timeout: 0,
next: '#next2',
prev: '#prev2',
after: function(){$('.caption').html('<a href=' + this.alt + '>' + this.title +
'</a>');}
});

$('#projects_tab a,.caption a').click(function(){    
selectedTab = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#'));
openTab(selectedTab);

//$("#projects_tab").animate({right: '-700'}, 1000);
$('#projects_b').addClass('active');
$("#projects_tab").hide();
$("#content").hide();
});
```

This is the code i'm using now, but it doesn't work all the times. Any clue why ? Here's the current version of the website:

www.dimitrinube.com/work/a2bc_beta2